# Jersey consume does not receive Multiple JSON Objects and Arrays

Tags: java, json, rest

Java Code:
      import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

//ContactDetails TO Object

```
      @XmlRootElement
     public class ContactDetails {
        private String name;
        private String address;

        public String getName() {
     return name;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
    return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
   }

 }
```

package com.rest.test.to;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

//PreviousEducationDetails TO Object

```
  @XmlRootElement
  public class PreviousEducationDetails {
  private String qualification;
  private String istitutionName;
  public String getQualification() {
          return qualification;
  }
  public void setQualification(String qualification) {
         this.qualification = qualification;
  }
  public String getIstitutionName() {
         return istitutionName;
  }
  public void setIstitutionName(String istitutionName) {
         this.istitutionName = istitutionName;
  }
```

}

//PersonalDetails TO Object

package com.rest.test.to;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class PersonalDetails {

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

}

//Javascript Code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#studentInsert").click(function() {
    alert("Reaches script !!");
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();

    student.presonal_details = {
            firstName : $("#firstName").val(),
            lastName : $("#lastName").val(),
            address : $("#address").val(),
            }
    student.contactPersonDetails=[{
        name:"Name1",
        address:"location1"
    },{
        name:"Name2",
        address:"location2"
    },{
        name:"Name3",
        address:"location3"
    }]
    student.previousEducationDetails=[
                                         {qualification:"MCA",istitutionName:"Engineering College"},
                                       {qualification:"MBA",istitutionName:"Engineering College"},
                                      {qualification:"Msc",istitutionName:"Engineering College"}
                                      ]
    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url :   "http://localhost:8080/RestJersey/rest/jsonRequestReceiver/saveStudentDetail",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data : JSON.stringify(student),
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

//Rest Resource method

```
 package com.rest.test;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.POST;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

 import com.rest.test.to.PersonalDetails;
 import com.rest.test.to.PreviousEducationDetails;
 import com.rest.test.to.StudentDetailsTO;
 @Path("/jsonRequestReceiver")
 public class JsonRequestReceiver {
 @POST
 @Path("/saveStudentDetail")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public void saveStudentDetail(StudentDetailsTO  student){
    }
  }
```

//StudentDetailsTO TO Object

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class StudentDetailsTO {

```
PersonalDetails personalDetails;
List<ContactDetails> contactDetails;
List<PreviousEducationDetails> previousEducationDetails;

public PersonalDetails getPersonalDetails() {
    return personalDetails;
}
public void setPersonalDetails(PersonalDetails personalDetails) {
    this.personalDetails = personalDetails;
}
    public List<ContactDetails> getContactDetails() {
    return contactDetails;
}
public void setContactDetails(List<ContactDetails> contactDetails) {
    this.contactDetails = contactDetails;
}
public List<PreviousEducationDetails> getPreviousEducationDetails() {
    return previousEducationDetails;
}
public void setPreviousEducationDetails(
        List<PreviousEducationDetails> previousEducationDetails) {
    this.previousEducationDetails = previousEducationDetails;
}
}
```

Error:

```
 Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
 Request             URL:http://localhost:8080/RestJersey/rest/jsonRequestReceiver/saveStudentD etail
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:400 Bad Request
 Request Headersview source
 Accept:*/*
 Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
 Cache-Control:no-cache
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:446
 Content-Type:application/json
 Host:localhost:8080
 Origin:http://localhost:8080
 Pragma:no-cache
 Referer:http://localhost:8080/RestJersey/
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,   like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/39.0.2171.65 Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36
  X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
  Request Payloadview source
 {presonal_details: {firstName: "Murugesan", lastName: "Rathinam",    address: "Karur"},…}
 contactPersonDetails: [{name: "Name1", address: "location1"}, {name:   "Name2", address: "location2"},…]
 presonal_details: {firstName: "Murugesan", lastName: "Rathinam",  address:  "Karur"}
 previousEducationDetails: [{qualification: "MCA", istitutionName:   "Engineering College"},…]
 Response Headersview source
 Connection:close
 Content-Type:text/plain
 Date:Tue, 28 Apr 2015 06:41:56 GMT
  Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Transfer-Encoding:chunked
   ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you provide a smaller example that still shows the behaviour?

Comment: Please add your error log

Comment: I want to send and receive one json object and two json array. At StudentDetailsTO contains those object and and List TO Class objects.

Comment: You have a typo (`student.presonal_details`) in your Javascript. You should also probably make it `personalDetails` to match your JavaBean property

Comment: This `student.contactPersonDetails` should be `student.contactDetails`. The JSON properties need to match your JavaBean property names, unless you use your serializer's custom annotations

Comment: Thank you Mr. peeskillet i got my code execute task ...